# Minecraft: Server problems

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

I have this problem in my server, let me explain it:

This Friday me and my friends bought a server on creeperhost.net, it's working great etc. We have been playing on the server now for two days on my laptop.

But then I switched from my laptop and started to play it on my new PC. The same server but now I'm having a weird problem. When I log in, I can't interact with the world, when I break a tree I don't get the log drop, whatever I do I can't do anything. 30 seconds later I get disconnected with the weird message "Internal exception: Java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"

Comment: Does the new PC work with other servers?

Comment: Does it still work with your laptop? And is java enabled for Firewall?